# Power BI REST API ExportToFileInGroup Not Working

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerbi-api

I am able to programmatically log in to the [PowerBI Client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp), gather my Workspaces as well as get a specific Report from a specific Workspace.  **I need to programmatically render that report to a .pdf or .xlsx file.**  Allegedly this is possible with the `ExportToFileInGroup`/`ExportToFileInGroupAsync` [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofileingroup).  I even created a very simple report without any parameters.  I can *embed* this using the sample app from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20organization).  So that at least tells me that I have what I need setup in the backend.  But it fails when I try to run the `ExportToFileInGroupAsync` method (errors below code.)

My Code is:

```
var accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] {
  PowerBiScopes.ReadReport,
  PowerBiScopes.ReadDataset,
});

var userInfo = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
var userName = userInfo.Mail;

AuthDetails authDetails = new AuthDetails {
  UserName = userName,
  AccessToken = accessToken,
};

var credentials = new TokenCredentials($"{accessToken}", "Bearer");
PowerBIClient powerBIClient = new PowerBIClient(credentials);

var groups = await powerBIClient.Groups.GetGroupsAsync();
var theGroup = groups.Value
  .Where(x => x.Name == "SWIFT Application Development")
  .FirstOrDefault();

var groupReports = await powerBIClient.Reports.GetReportsAsync(theGroup.Id);
var theReport = groupReports.Value
  .Where(x => x.Name == "No Param Test")
  .FirstOrDefault();

var exportRequest = new ExportReportRequest {
  Format = FileFormat.PDF,
};

string result = "";

try {
  var response = await powerBIClient.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(theGroup.Id, theReport.Id, exportRequest);
  result = response.ReportId.ToString();
} catch (Exception e) {
  result = e.Message;
}

return result;
```

It gets to the line in the `try` block and then throws the following errors:

*An error occurred while sending the request.*

*Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..*

**UPDATE**
Relating to @AndreyNikolov question, here is our Embedded capacity:
[image]

After this was implemented, no change.  Same exact error.

Comment: Is there a dedicated capacity assigned to the report's workspace?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I believe so. Is there a page I can go to or a call I can make to verify this? I am not the admin but have contact with him.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I also assume Yes because the Microsoft sample noted above works.  When I (not the admin) go to the https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/capacities/capacitiesList/azure I only see the graphic that says Learn More.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I have updated the post to show the capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was on our side, more specifically, security/firewall settings.  Here is the exact quote from our networking guru.

*"After some more investigation we determined that our firewall was causing this issue when it was terminating the SSL connection.  We were able to add a bypass for the URL and it is now working as expected."*